# Bathroom GFCI question

Tags: bathroom

In my apartment bathroom there is a GFCI receptacle with 2 switches on the wall directly to the right when walking in. There is also a receptacle right by the sink. Does the receptacle by the sink need to be GFCI protected or is it protected by the GFCI receptacle closer to the entry of the bathroom?

Answer (score 2):

It does need to be protected there by the sink. It may very well be wired into the LOAD terminals of the other GFCI outlet. It is easy for you to check. Plug a lamp in by the sink and turn it ON. Then press the TEST button on the GFCI outlet. If the lamp goes OFF you know that the outlets are coupled.

Comment: To directly answer the question, if the test @Michael Karas outlined is successful, the outlet *is* protected by the GFI receptacle near the entry. If the test does not work, it proves only that it is not protected by that entry receptacle; however it might (or might not) be GFI protected by a *different* receptacle, or by a GFI circuit breaker.

Comment: You can also buy outlet testers with a CFGI test button, for example, http://www.homedepot.com/p/Gardner-Bender-120-VAC-GFCI-Outlet-Tester-1-clam-5-clams-master-GFI-3501/202867890. You can plug this into the sink outlet and press the test button. If the tester lights go out, the outlet is protected (and now you need to go find the GFCI that's protecting it).